# Single HTML rendering differently on desktop Vs iPad

Tags: html, ipad, css

I am trying to create a fluid/responsive layout where the same HTML would render differently on different devices...Now I am aware of how to use CSS Media queries (for desktop/iPad,etc), fluid grids and all that stuff..

My question is let's say these are the 2 layouts i have for desktop/iPad..I need to design using a single HTML and have 2 separate CSS (which would be ofcouse through the media query device-width, etc)...How do I code my HTML such that the CSS would be able to render it differently?

**Desktop layout**
[image]
**iPad layout**
[image: iPad layout]

I have already gone through many articles like the one on;
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

But my question is is it possible to create extremely different views from a single HTML just through CSS (By that I would mean say a particular set of sections/cols showing on desktop is at a very differnt position for a different device)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last I checked, you could add the `media` tag in the CSS file and it would automatically do this for you.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css" media="Screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css" media="handheld" />
```

**Example**

```
<div id="header"></div>
    <div class="centerSection"></div>
    <div class="centerSection"></div>
    <div class="centerSection">
        <div></div><div></div>
    </div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

**Desktop**

```
.centerSection { float:left; }
```

**Mobile**

```
.centerSection { clear:both; }
```

See here: [W3 CSS Media](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html)

Comment: I am aware of adding the media query..my question is how do i plan to code the html and the css to render differently ?

Comment: Well, you could just code the HTML and CSS for the desktop, and then write the CSS file for the mobile version. There isn't much different, as long as you follow good conventions on creating a website/css file to begin with. Using the second CSS file, you can simply change the layout and hide whatever sections are unnecessary on the mobile version. I guess one thing to keep in mind would be to know what for sure WILL be on both versions. (That way you can hide certain `<div>` that you don't need.)

Comment: Hiding the div for desktop vs ipad would be the easy part..i am not sure how to code the sections center a and center b which appear at diff places on desktop vs ipad..

Comment: instead of having center a and center b `float:left;`, you would have `clear:both;`

Comment: Could u pls add a rough code for both html and the css so that i can understand better..

Comment: Actually if u see layout, the order changes for A and B in desktop vs ipad..on desktop b comes first, while on iPad, A is at the top...so guess, we need to consider that as well...

Comment: well, it will work either way - you just need to play with the containers to get the effect you want. you would probably need another class.